# How to logout with flask_jwt_extended

Tags: python, flask

Generating jwt with flask_jwt_extended.

**creating token**

```
create_access_token(identity=identity)
```

i couldn't find anything about logout. Revoking jwt token

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define a callback function via the `token_in_blocklist_loader()` decorator.

In practice you'd have some DB where you are keeping track of this.

I don't know what you mean by did not find anything, there is [a documentation on revoking](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blocklist_and_token_revoking/) it that has some good advice.